# How can I return to England as a British citizen with a Philippine passport?

Tags: passports, uk-citizens, dual-nationality, filipino-citizens

As a British citizen, are you allowed to enter back with a non-British passport?

Can I still use my Philippine passport to go in Philippines and back to England using it?

Comment: For what purpose? Even if it's allowed, you would need a visa in your Philippine passport to be allowed to enter the UK and I doubt that the UK would issue a visa to their own citizens, just so that you can use a foreign passport to enter.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo, it might seem crazy, but yes they sometimes do exactly that.  One such case.....  https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/118569/immigration-right-of-abode.pdf

Comment: @GayotFow You are linking to a 14 page document. What exactly do you mean?

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo, RoA stickers and Certificate of Entitlement stickers.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo, there's a lot of Brits holding them who would disagree with that. I suggest reading it again.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo It does seem to indicate that a certificate of entitlement can, in fact, be issued to a British citizen. Otherwise, why write “if the person holds a *current* British citizen passport”?

Comment: What happened to your British passport?

Comment: @Relaxed right. It's the preferred modus operandi for people who want them. And for some reason, LOTS of dual nationals (me for example) like to have it.  Let your British passport expire, get a ROA in your foreign one, renew your British passport. Or just hang on to the one you got prior to 2006. The main point being that the original comment raised an corner case. But being helpful didn't help in this case.  Done here.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo There might be a small misunderstanding. Someone edited the title but the OP did not originally indicate whether he or she currently holds a valid British passport.

Comment: I am completely confused. Why did Kate Gregory edit the title and add that the OP is a holder of a UK passport? Was there something in the original question or in the text indicating that?

Comment: I don't know why, but I also understood the original question as if the OP had both passports. If that's not the case, my comments don't make much sense. I deleted most of them.

Answer (score 4):

Paragraph 12 of the Immigration Rules says...

> ```
> A person claiming to be a British citizen must prove that he has the right of abode in the 
> United Kingdom by producing either:
> (i) a United Kingdom passport describing him as a British citizen or as a citizen of the 
> United Kingdom and Colonies having the right of abode in the United Kingdom; or
> (ii) a certificate of entitlement duly issued by or on behalf of the Government of the 
> United Kingdom certifying that he has the right of abode.
> ```

So a passport is required to enter the UK *as a British Citizen*.

If you do not, or cannot produce a British passport, then Paragraph 7 kicks in.  It says...

> A person who is neither a British citizen nor a Commonwealth citizen
>   with the right of abode  nor a person who is entitled to enter or
>   remain in the United Kingdom by virtue of the provisions  of the 2006
>   EEA Regulations requires leave to enter the United Kingdom.

That means they will inspect your Philippine passport for your UK visa (specifically, an entry clearance issued by a consular post abroad) or UK permanent residence or UK right of abode stamps. If they find a valid 'leave to enter', they will use it to admit you.   The terms and conditions of that visa will apply.

If they do not find a suitable 'leave to enter' in your Philippine passport, you will be detained and you will have to think up something to explain your circumstances.  Your biometrics will be taken to see if they sync up to your explanation.  They are also likely to run your biometrics through Interpol and the DHS.  If they are satisfied with your explanation, you will be admitted under Paragraph 18 of the rules, *OR* you will get a temporary admission with the condition of reporting to the police within a certain amount of time.

If they are not satisfied with your explanation, then you will be vulnerable to being served removal instructions.

Answer (score 2):

It's not forbidden to use another passport but in practice the main problem you will face is that Philippines citizens need a visa to visit the UK. Without a UK visa or a passport to establish your British citizenship, you would most likely be denied boarding in the Philippines and would not even get the chance to explain your situation at the UK border.